# How can I create a view in SQL Server Management Studio using different where clause statements in it?

Tags: sql-server

I have created some tables in the database, and I want to create a single view by picking columns from all those tables.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_Name
AS
    SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2, c.column1, c.column2
    FROM
        table1 AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table2 AS b ON a.column1 = b.column1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table3 AS c ON b.column2 = c.column2
    WHERE   
    (a.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date)
        From table1)

        and (b.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date)
        From table2)

        and (c.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date)
        From table3)

go
```

While I am trying to use multiple where clauses and complete the query, it is throwing me an error 'Incorrect Statement near 'go'.

I an new to SQL Server and I am stuck here. Can any one help me with completing my query with no errors?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra LEFT OUTER JOIN after table3 (before WHERE)

Comment: It would help you if you formatted your SQL differently, when you're joining your tables then start the line with this followed by the table instead of declaring the JOIN at the end of the line and the table name on the next one. Some simple changes will make bug solving much easier.

Comment: I just edited my query, please take a look into it.

Comment: Delete `GO` - it's needed only as separator in case of multiple DDL statements in script. What is your result now?

Comment: you've got too few brackets, or too many brackets, in the WHERE - depending on how you look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your brackets in the WHERE are muddled - try this

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View_Name

AS

SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2, c.column1, c.column2

FROM
table1 AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN

table2 AS b ON a.column1 = b.column1 LEFT OUTER JOIN

table3 AS c ON b.column2 = c.column2

WHERE
(a.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date) From table1))

and (b.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date) From table2))

and (c.[Load_Date] = (select max(Load_Date) From table3))

go
```

Comment: Might as well change those `LEFT JOIN`s to an `INNER JOIN` too; the tables are referenced in the `WHERE` without handling `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite what you have as follows:

```
WITH T1 AS
    (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
            Column1,
            Column2
     FROM Table1
     ORDER BY Load_Date DESC),
T2 AS
    (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
            Column1,
            Column2
     FROM Table2
     ORDER BY Load_Date DESC),
T3 AS
    (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
            Column1,
            Column2
     FROM Table3
     ORDER BY Load_Date DESC)
SELECT *
FROM T1
     JOIN T2 ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
     JOIN T3 ON T2.Column1 = T2.Column2;
```

Note I have used `JOIN`, as you reference the objects from the `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE`, making them implicit `INNER JOIN`s.